# Basic JS - Why does this obj not change to undefined?

Tags: javascript, object, reference

In the below code, I understand why `person.name` is changed to `"john"`, but I do not understand fully why `person` does not reference `undefined` in memory, per the `obj = undefined` on the next line.

```
var person = { name: "wtf" };

function doStuff(obj) {
  obj.name = "john";
  obj = undefined;
  }

doStuff(person);
```

`person.name` now equals `john` and `person` still references or "points" to the object instead of "pointing" to nothing in memory, i.e. undefined. I could carry forward in my learning and simply rely on this to work this way, but I'd never be able to articulate exactly why it works this way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object references to undefined in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22044780/object-references-to-undefined-in-javascript)

Comment: Also relevant: [JavaScript - How/Can I set an object reference to null from a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205070/javascript-how-can-i-set-an-object-reference-to-null-from-a-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `obj` parameter in your function is passed a reference to `person` in the function call

```
doStuff(person);
```

The parameter value is a **copy** of the object reference stored in `person`. When you give the `obj` variable a new value, therefore, that has no effect on `person`.

Comment: To be clear, you could say the parameter value (which is a copy) simply references something else now? In this case, undefined.

Comment: @colbisaurusrex yes exactly. You've just updated that parameter's value, so the original value (the copy of the object reference) is overwritten.